# Как выполнить сложение чисел?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Есть массив, в котором хранятся числа. Каким образом сложить их и получить сумму всех чисел массива?

```
    $n_itog = implode($arrst, '+');
    $itog = $n_itog;
    echo $itog;
```

> $arrst - массив с числами. Array ( [0] => 3352620 [1] => 56815 )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте стандартную функцию:

```
$itog = array_sum($arrst);
```